# Ajax return gets two different values from database

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a normal ajax function which posts to a php page and returns some items from a table.

Everything was fine until I tried to set the user's FB image. I was getting this error:

```
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request.",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
}
```

While checking with Chrome's inspect element I noticed something weird.

This is the `Preview` tab in `Network`:

```
active: 1
add_date: "2015-03-11 05:28:10"
fb_id: ...828
first_name: "Fname"
id: 468
item_description: "Desc"
item_title: "Title"
user_id: 62
username: ""
```

And this is in the `Response` tab in `Network`

```
[{"id":468,"user_id":62,"item_title":"Title","item_description":"Desc","active":1,"add_date":"2015-03-11 05:28:10","fb_id":...829,"first_name":"Fname","username":""}]
```

Everything is the same except the `fb_id` which is decremented by one. In the users table it ends in `829`.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Edit **

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url:"ajax/realpha.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { 'tab' : tab },
  success: function(data) {

    $(tab).empty();
    jQuery.each(data, function(i) {
       console.log(data[i].fb_id);
    ');
    });

  }
});
```

realpha.php

```
  $selectHome = $ItemTools->selectHome();

  echo json_encode($selectHome);
```

Query

```
 public function selectHome() {
    if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT
            t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.item_title, t1.item_number, t1.item_start, t1.item_description, t1.active, t2.first_name, t2.last_name, t2.fb_id, b.maxbid, b.bids
            FROM
              items t1
            LEFT JOIN
              users t2
            ON
              t1.user_id = t2.id
            LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT item_id, bid, MAX(bid) AS maxbid, COUNT(bid) AS bids
              FROM bids GROUP BY item_id
            ) b
            ON t1.id = b.item_id
            WHERE t1.active = 1
            ORDER BY id DESC")) {
    $q->execute();

    $rows = $this->db->bindResults($q);

    $q->close();

    return $rows;

    }

}
```

Comment: May you share the code you are using.

Comment: Hi ... It's a lot. Can you tell me if there is any difference between the data I see in the preview and response tab in inspect element? Why would only that particular field be affected? The row is set as `bigint` ... if that makes any difference.

Comment: Want to see code just to check what you are fetching and sending to client.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 see my edit please. Just checked the console log ... it's still one less than the actual fb_id that is stored in the database.

Comment: probably a typo, `console.log(data[i]fb_id);` should be `console.log(data[i].fb_id);` (with the dot)

Comment: Yes ... forgot the .

Comment: Code looks fine. May you cross check db entry...

Comment: Just did :) in the db it's 829 and the above returns 828. But it returns both. That's what I don't get. There are two different values when I check with inspect element. In the Network tab there is nne value in Preview and one in Response.

Comment: What happens in Firebug? Same deal?

Comment: Haven t checked in firebug. I will. good idea. thank you

Comment: Same thing in Firebug.

Comment: Is this consistent problem for all records or with this id only?

Comment: just the fb_id. column

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your database has auto_increment on the `fb_id` field in the `users` table?

It might be a smart idea to show the create table statements.

Comment: No ... it has auto increment on the `id` field.